# Keep selected option in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have below code which runs query correctly but does not keep selected option. I could get similar answers but not worked with this code. Here select options are in combination of user given and rest are from mysql column.
I am new to php, so any help will be appreciated.

```
<select name="tester"> 

<option value=""> -----------ALL----------- </option> 
<?php

$dd_res=mysqli_query($conn, "Select DISTINCT tester from workflow1");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($dd_res))
    { 
     echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
     }
 ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="find" value="find"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$_POST` superglobal array to check the value of submitted form fields. In this case `$_POST['tester']` contains the value of the select field after submitting the form.

```
echo "<option value='$r[0]'".($_POST['tester']==$r[0]?' selected':'')."> $r[0] </option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you are asking to select the value passed into the form? If I am correct in that, you would do something like:

```
$selVal = $_REQUEST['tester'];
$val = $r[0];
echo '<option value="'.$val.'"';
if ($val == $selVal) {
  echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo '>'.$val.'</option>';
```

The $_REQUEST gets any POST, GET or COOKIE value and should be validated to make sure no hack attempts or anything. Once you have the value, you just add the selected attribute if it matches the value in the list.